# OpenForm Macro Not working when query has two tables

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

Hello Access 2010 new user here and I am trying to figure out a problem I am having with a embedded macro button. The setup is I have a couple of forms that gives me a summary view of some records that I filter with a query. I want to be able to click a button that will let me look at all of the queried records on a new form with an expanded view.

I'm Using a button with an embedded macro to do this using a filter name of the same query I used to get the summary. Here is the Button macro I have set up: [Image of the embedded Macro](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B9iLd.png)

It works great and gives me all 10 records that I want using this query: [Image of the query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5yc8W.png) The problem comes when I use a query that uses more than one table. [Image of query with two tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/39cKI.png)

All of the parameters are the same except instead of querying for a single employee I am querying for the entire team. When I use the team query Access asks me for the team name parameter and even if I enter that manually, it doesn't ask me for the other parameters and it doesn't filter for those missing parameters. Does anyone have any idea why this is happening or have a way to fix it?

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help and make your question readable by inserting paragraphs.

Comment: Popup prompt means Access can't find control referenced in the query criteria. Are you sure spelling is correct? What is stored in the Team field - descriptive text or a foreign key? Since the issue here is design, not code, not easy to analyze without direct examination.

Comment: I've checked the spelling over and over. The team field is a lookup field to another table that stores the team names. TblUser is storing the ID number of the team. (Foreign key I guess?) I could upload the front end - but I don't know if that would give you what you want. I cant release the back end because it has personnel info.

Comment: The database can be found [Here.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/6ieabnca040yntj/QADBUploadVersion.accdb?dl=0) Thank you all for your time and help! You will need to login using Username:auser PW:1111 or the database will not work. The problematic button that isnt working is on the QA Tab under Team Trends.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upload access file with this two table making it local to file and fill out dummy data in table.